# Does $http sort the params object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, unit-testing, http

I writing some unit tests for my angularjs app. For the tests I'm mocking the $http request with the internal $httpBackend.

During the test I use the $httpBackend.expectGET, because I want the exact behavior of my app request.

For example I have an Params-Object:

```
parameters = {
        name : 'Monkey',
        crazy : false,
        desc : 'Nobody',
      };
```

The Http-Get request in my app is:

```
return $http.get(this.uri + '/' + id, {params : parameters});
```

At my unit-test I expect this:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(instance.uri + '/' + returnValues.id + '?' + query).respond(200, object);
```

"query" is only the elements of the object concat with '=' and '&'. 
So I **expect** the URL:

```
 www.example.com/api/v1/object/1?name=Monkey&crazy=false&desc=Nobody
```

But I get this one:

```
www.example.com/api/v1/object/1?crazy=false&desc=Nobody&name=Monkey
```

Does $http make a sort on basis of the keys in the object for the *"params"*?

Comment: try shuffling them around in your object and see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `$http` sorts the parameters before sending them to the server according to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L21)

```
forEachSorted(params, function(value, key) {
    ...
});
```

So your tests should expect ordered keys, or your can write your own paramSerializer by sending it to the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) provider:

> **paramSerializer** - *{string|function(Object):string}* - A function used
>   to prepare string representation of request parameters (specified as
>   an object). Is specified as string, it is interpreted as function
>   registered in with the {$injector}.

Comment: But what is the purpose? For the server it should make a difference, or did it?

Comment: The server *shouldn't* care, but I would imagine it's so that the resulting params string can be easily asserted during unit tests. As objects have no guaranteed order in JS, it's better to make sure the keys are sorted

Comment: Thank You, RGraham. :-) But this was very unexpected for me, that angular respectively $http sort the params for me...